# Messages going to the Mac from my iPod

Tags: macos, icloud, messages

Every time I have a message sent to me, it's sent to my family's Mac and my iPod. How do I get them to stop going to my Mac? I have already tried looking into Settings and "Send and Receive" but all I have in there is my Apple ID and email.

Comment: Does everyone share the same Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign out of FaceTime and Messages on the device that you want to control better.
2. Write down on a piece of paper all the Apple ID that are logged in to messages and FaceTime on the affected pool of devices.
3. De-register your cellular number from other people's AppleID at https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage
4. Sign in with your AppleID on only the select devices you want to receive messages.

Test. At that point, you can ask a follow-on question with a short list of the unique accounts and unique devices and/or ask if there is an Apple support article similar to the one that documents how to remove a phone number from an email (for instance) if that's not the sticking point.